Bot crawling getting 301/redirects instead of 404 so it's hiding from fail2ban. How is it getting 301 intead of 404?
I have fail2ban setup and it's working great for most scanning. It triggers off any 4xx in the nginx error log. However, note the following bot scan. Somehow THIS bot is triggering my server to return 301 instead of 404, like all the others. How could it be doing this? Since it's a 301 and not a 4xx, it walked right past my fail2ban and never got banned. I'd like to detect and prevent this.
Any suggestion on how this was done and how to prevent it?
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:49 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:49 +0000] "GET /.DS_Store HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.0 Safari/605.1.15"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:49 +0000] "GET /.env HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:49 +0000] "POST /.env HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:106.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/106.0"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:50 +0000] "GET /.env.prod HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:50 +0000] "POST /.env.prod HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:50 +0000] "GET /.env.production HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:51 +0000] "POST /.env.production HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:51 +0000] "GET /redmine/.env HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:51 +0000] "POST /redmine/.env HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:52 +0000] "GET /__tests__/test-become/.env HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:52 +0000] "POST /__tests__/test-become/.env HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:106.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/106.0"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:52 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:53 +0000] "GET /debug/default/view?panel=config HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:53 +0000] "GET /debug/default/view.html HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:53 +0000] "GET /debug/default/view HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:54 +0000] "GET /frontend/web/debug/default/view HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:54 +0000] "GET /web/debug/default/view HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:54 +0000] "GET /sapi/debug/default/view HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:54 +0000] "GET /_profiler/phpinfo HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:55 +0000] "GET /app_dev.php/_profiler/phpinfo HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:55 +0000] "GET /phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:55 +0000] "GET /owncloud/apps/graphapi/vendor/microsoft/microsoft-graph/tests/GetPhpInfo.php HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:56 +0000] "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0"
178.20.44.82 - - [30/May/2024:21:28:56 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

My only 301 redirects are the ones certbot set up:
server { if ($host = www.mydomainname.com) 
    { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; } # managed by Certbot 
if ($host = mydomainname.com) 
    { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; } # managed by Certbot 


Where do you have wildcard redirect rules in the web server config?  http -> https?  old-hostname -> new-hostname?

Making a request without a Host: header?

My redirects are the ones certbot set up:
server {
if ($host = www.mydomainname.com) {
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot
    if ($host = mydomainname.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

I have no idea how to get this to format as readable code......

Please put new information and updates into your question. You can format code there by selecting a block and using the {} button

The bot gets a 301 Redirect because it tries to access a HTTP page, hence the nginx configuration snippet you posted redirects it to HTTPS.
You might try configuring nginx to do a URL rewrite instead of a redirect, changing the Certbot-generated snippet to this one:
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name www.mydomainname.com mydomainname.com;
    
   location / {
      rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
   }
}


Any risk of just returning 404 for anyone accessing the site via http?  It's not really a public use site but for a dev API server.  Not sure how this would affect the CertBot renewal.

Sure, you can do that by editing the Certbot-generated snippet to return an error 404 instead of 301. I don't see any risk in doing that and (I guess) this shouldn't affect the renewal of certificates. Be careful as this will break the workflow of anyone accessing the API via HTTP.
